# Constraint in RGLPK optimisation that depends on the result of the optimization

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, glpk

I want to add a constraint to my linear optimization that is maybe not really linear.

Let's say my optimizer has to select 10 elements among 100. Each element has a score, contained in the vector `score`, that has a length of 100. Each element has a coefficient, contained in the vector `coefficient`, that has a length of 100.
My constraint is: `(score * optim) %*% (coefficient * optim)/sum(coefficient * optim)>50`, where optim is a vector with a 1 if the element is selected and 0 otherwise.

Any idea how I can write this constraint, as sum(coefficient * optim) depends on the result of the optimization?

Comment: This seems a little more appropriate for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), since it is about the math and not the programming.

Answer (score 0):

You just can use what you wrote down. Well, almost. I think

```
(score * optim) %*% (coefficient * optim)/sum(coefficient * optim)>50
```

means

```
sum(i, score[i]*coefficient[i]*sqr(optim[i])) / sum(i,coefficient[i]*optim[i]) >= 50
sum(i, optim[i]) = 10   (select 10 best) 
optim[i] in {0,1}       (binary variables)
```

(I am using here some pseudo math notation). This can be rewritten as:

```
sum(i, score[i]*coefficient[i]*optim[i]) >= 50*sum(i,coefficient[i]*optim[i])
sum(i, optim[i]) = 10   (select 10 best) 
optim[i] in {0,1}       (binary variables)
```

This is perfectly linear in the binary variables `optim[i]`.